# Is it possible to deploy by filename using the new CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, metadata, salesforcedx-cli, cli

I have been using a command from the old CLI: `sfdx force:source:deploy -p "/path/to/filename.cls"` to deploy by filename.

Is this possible using the new CLI?

I do see an example of `sf project deploy start --source-dir path/to/apex/classes/MyClass.cls path/to/source/objects` in the help, but I'm not sure if this is what I am looking for because it has a second parameter added.

Or do I have to deploy by metadata?

Comment: Did you even try to do it? Yes it is correct command

Comment: @user1974566 Why does it have a path added to the parameter? I didn't pass a path before. I didn't try it before I understand what is the difference

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look further down in [the documentation on `sf project deploy start`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_project_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_project_deploy_start_unified), it'll go over the individual flags in more detail.

Directly quoting that documentation:

> -d | --source-dir SOURCE-DIR
> Optional
>
> Path to the local source files to deploy.
>
> The supplied path can be to a single file (in which case the operation is applied to only one file) or to a folder (in which case the operation is applied to all metadata types in the directory and its subdirectories).
>
> If you specify this flag, don’t specify --metadata or --manifest.

So yes, that's what you're looking for. The example shows deploying a single file from one folder in addition to everything in a different folder.

`sf project deploy start -d /path/to/filename.cls` ought to work
that said
`sf project deploy start -m ApexClass:ClassName` is probably going to be less typing, and would achieve the same result.

Comment: Small typo, the last line should be `ApexClass:ClassName` and not `ApexClass:filename` (which implies the `.cls` should be included).

Comment: @sfdcfox fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `project deploy start` command is the approximately equivalent command as `force:source:deploy`. See the [`force:source:deploy documentation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_deploy) for the list of differences between the two commands. `-p, --sourcepath` has been renamed to `-d, --source-dir`, as shown in the migration table.